# MSSQL error #120

Tags: sql-server

I have the following sql:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table1]
    ([col1],[col2],[col3],...[col14])
SELECT * FROM [dbo].Table2
GO
```

Running it throws MSSQL Err #120 which means the number of columns line up to the INSERT. table2 has 5 columns and table1 has 14. Would I be correct in assuming that this is the cause of the error? The reason I ask is that a) Not familiar with **MSSQL** and b) I am unfamiliar with their database.

Comment: it's MSSQL and I'm viewing in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: THey have to have the same number of columns `INSERT INTO t1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) SELECT * FROM t2` where t2 has 5 columns

Comment: Don't use select * for inserts. You should ALWAYS be explicit in your columns. Why bother naming the columns in only half of the query??

Comment: Right? I didn't write the query. It's a new client's an I am unfamiliar with that method of insert.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is because table1 and table2 have a different number of columns.

Comment: you can do 'USE master SELECT * FROM sys.messages where message_id=120' and it will give you the associated error text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the cause of your error.

You will have to:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table1]
    ([col1],[col2],[col3],...[col14])
SELECT 
    col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, --your table's columns
    'const1', null, 1, etc... --other values that you want for the other columns, 
FROM [dbo].Table2             --defaults, constants, null, etc.

GO
```

or

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table1]
    ([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5]) --the rest will have their default value.
SELECT 
    col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM [dbo].Table2
GO
```